# Como obter as coordenadas x e y em um círculo a partir de um ângulo

Tags: java, matemática, canvas, bitmap, coordenadas

[image]
Estou tentando criar um relógio analógico e minha ideia era a seguinte obtinha o ângulo correspondente a hora e depois descobria a posição x e y desse ângulo em um círculo e desenhava uma linha do centro do meu relógio até às determinada posições para assim exibir os ponteiros. Porém estou tendo dificuldades em obter as posições desse ângulo. Meu código até agora é esse:

```
calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int h = Integer.valueOf(new SimpleDateFormat("hh").format(calendar.getTime()));
        int m = Integer.valueOf(new SimpleDateFormat("mm").format(calendar.getTime()));
        a = (h * 30) + (m / 2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro você tem que saber qual a direção o ponteiro sera exibido (Exemplo: na hora 3 em 27 minutos) e depois você tera que fazer um calculo para saber as condenada Y e X em que o ponteiro vai marca na direção correspondente ao horário

**Exemplo em imagem**
[image: A imagem representa um circulo com 360°, e seus valores em H e M]

Nessa imagem a um circulo com 360° (E na teórica a min = -160 & max = 160) e ela tem o parâmetro H e cada H tem um parâmetro M, assim ao completar 4h, nos conseguinos dar a volta no círculo (resultado de 360°) e como você tambem usa os minutos, somamos o parâmetro M do H, e tambem completamos 1h completo

**Exemplo em código**

```
double h = 360/4; 
double m = h/4;
double result = h*3 + m*4;

System.out.println(result); 
//Log: 360.0
```

**Obs:** Agora você pegando esse resultado, você faz um sistema pra definir a direção exata de cada ponteiro em seu eixo X e Y

```
int x = 680;
int y = 680;

int eixoX = y / ...
int eixoY = x / ...

//Cada unidade vai ser um valor simultâneo entre a direção do círculo e o eixo do ponteiro
//direção: 117 = 90°
//eixo: 36 = 90°

resultX = eixoX * result;
resultY = eixoY * result;
```